# Using a list as a class parameter

Tags: python, list, class, oop

```
class Interface():
    def __init__(self, localIP, remoteIP, numHops, hops):
        self.localIP = localIP
        self.remoteIP = remoteIP
        self.numHops = numHops
        self.hops = []
```

I want to create an instance like this:

```
hops, hopIps = stripRoute(ssh.run("traceroute -I " + str(dstHost.ip), hide=True))
host.interfaces.append(Interface(host.ip, dstHost.ip, hops, hopIps))
print(hops)
print(hopIps)
```

From the print statements I can see that hopIps has a value and length 1 which is expected. However when I then query the new instance of Interface, only the numHops value was updated, hops remains empty.

Comment: Side note: Is it really necessary to have `numHops`? Shouldn't it always be equal to `len(hops)`?

Comment: If the packet only passes through a switch it wont be recorded as a hop(ttl value of packet wont decrease) and therefore len(hops) would be zero but the numHops value would remain 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You passed a list into `__init__` but never used it

```
class Interface():
    def __init__(self, localIP, remoteIP, numHops, hops):
        self.localIP = localIP
        self.remoteIP = remoteIP
        self.numHops = numHops
        self.hops = []
```

Just assign your list to the member

```
class Interface():
    def __init__(self, localIP, remoteIP, numHops, hops):
        self.localIP = localIP
        self.remoteIP = remoteIP
        self.numHops = numHops
        self.hops = hops
```

Comment: maybe you want to make make a copy of `hops` like this `self.hops = hops.copy()` to prevent some unwanted behavior?